# Is it possible to position something on top of the flot graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flot

I have a flot graph and I have a couple divs that I want to place on top of it. Is there a way I can do this?

Here's a folded version of the HTML code:

```
<div id='graph'>
    <div id='selectionBox'>
    </div>

    <div id='valueBoard'>
    </div>

    <table style="position:absolute">
    </table>

    <table id="gridTable" style="position:absolute">
    </table>
</div>
```

The flot is linked to the graph ID. The divs used to sit on top the graph ID div but they don't anymore.

Comment: Do you mean appearing first in the flow or do you mean closer to the screen, ie z-index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** have content in `flots` container div.   It controls the content of the div programmtically and will clear it before rendering the plot.

A workaround would be to programmtically position your *child* divs on top of `flots` container:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", someData, {});
var pos = $('#placeholder').position();
$('#somethingElse').css({'top': pos.top,
                         'left': pos.left});
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eK5kn/).

Comment: Thanks! It's not what I was hoping for but I can make it work.